# How to set Aspect ratios of all videos in FFMPEG ?

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to concatenate 3 videos using a C# wrapper class. (NRECO.Videoconverter)

All the videos have the same frame rate and size.

However Aspect ratio of the second video is different.

How can I set all the aspect ratio of the three videos to be the same. I would like to set the aspect ratio of the second video to be the same as the first and and third one.

Here is what I have tried in C# using the wrapper class.

```
ConcatSettings concatSettings = new ConcatSettings
 {
    CustomOutputArgs = "-filter_complex \"[1:v]setsar=1[v1];[0:v:0][0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] [2:v:0] [2:a:0] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[outv] [outa]\" \\-map \"[outv]\" -map \"[outa]\""

 };

fFMpeg.ConcatMedia(inputfiles, finaloutput, Format.mp4, concatSettings);
```

This gives me errors saying -

```
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 04ded5e0] Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 852x480, SAR 160:213) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (852x480, SAR 12800:9443)
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 04ded5e0] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_0
Error configuring complex filters.
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use

```
"-filter_complex \"[0:v]setsar=1[v0];[1:v]setsar=1[v1];[2:v]setsar=1[v2];[v0][0:a:0] [v1][1:a:0] [v2][2:a:0] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[outv] [outa]\"
```

Comment: This lets me run the command without any errors, but It does not concat the second video. It just concats the first and third and runs.

Comment: Share full log.